# Converting Data Type from data.table package in R

Tags: r, data.table

this might be a dumb/obvious question but unfortunately I haven't had much luck finding information about it online so I thought I'd ask it here. Basically, I'm working with the data.table package in R and I have imported a data set into R where, in a particular column, the values can be both numeric values and character values (and even blank/empty values), and I want to be able to obtain a value from that column and use it for calculations.

The thing about the data.table package though is that when you import a file using the fread() function it automatically sets all values in that file as a character data type, so this can cause a few issues since this means that all numbers are automatically character types as well. I have worked around this slightly by using the as.numeric() function so that if a value obtained from that column is a number then it can be easily converted to numeric type and used in calculations. However, since the column also contains other characters (specifically, it can also have \N or N as values) and since it can also contain blank/empty values, then this means the as.numeric() function will show up with an error. For example, I initially wrote an IF loop to detect whether a column cell had a character value or a numeric value as follows:

```
if( as.numeric(..{Reference to column cell from file here}...) == NA ) {
x <- 0
}
```

(where x is just some variable), but it did not work and instead gave the output:

```
Error in if ((as.numeric(.... : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

(I should note that is.numeric() also did not work since all values in a data.table data set are automatically character values so this function always gives FALSE regardless of it's actual data type).

So clearly I need a better function or method to work around this. Is there a function capable of reading a 'character' value from a column and being able to detect whether that value is truly a numeric type or character type (or even neither, in the case of an empty cell)? Thanks in advance

Comment: `DT[is.na(as.numeric(variable)), variable := 0]`, but you should be sure that's what you really want. Typically, I would just do `DT[ , variable := as.numeric(variable)]` and leave the character entries as missing, unless you want to extract some other data from those values first.

Comment: Thanks, this works quite well :) It still comes up with a warning message but it looks like it should be fine. I just have a few general questions: firstly what do you mean by " you should be sure that's what you really want"? Does this particular function have issues etc.? Also, I originally did want to leave the characters as missing but I wasn't sure how to. If I only use the function `DT[ , variable := as.numeric(variable)]` wouldn't that just cause the same issues I had before since the character data types can't be converted to numeric data types?

Comment: Examine `as.numeric('foo')`. If the character entries of your data contain relevant information (e.g., there are different types of missingness), you will want to extract this information before wiping it out by converting it to `NA`. For example by creating separate indicators.

Comment: Whichever of those codes are legit missing values can be indicated as such with the `na.strings` argument to `fread`. Then you can examine the rest after reading in like `DT[!is.na(x) & is.na(as.numeric(x)), .N, by=x]` to debug. Btw, don't do `if (vector){ ... }`. Either you're passing the whole vector in which case only the first element will be used; or you're doing it by row, which is very inefficient. Note that we cannot tell which of these two cases applies here since you chose not to provide an example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before your next post.